# Contador de Strings no ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, contador

Eu preciso que o programa retorne a quantidade de vezes que cada `String` se repetiu dentro do `ArrayList`, porém não consegui pensar em um jeito em que meu contador seja reaproveitado por cada item, pois como mostra ali na saída, fala que o dado 3 repetiu 4, 5 e 6 vezes. Seria melhor fazer uma função pública e apenas chamá-la na `main`? Como posso resolver?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<String> dados= new ArrayList<String>();
    dados.add("Dado 2");
    dados.add("Dado 1");
    dados.add("Dado 3");
    dados.add("Dado 3");
    dados.add("Dado 2");
    dados.add("Dado 1");
    dados.add("Dado 3");
    dados.add("Dado 3");
    Collections.sort(dados);  
    //while(dados.contains(dados)){
      //  System.out.println("deu certo");
    //}       
    //for (String x : dados){
    //    System.out.println(x);
    //    if (x.contains(x))
   // }     
    int i;
    int contador = 0;
    int x = 1;
    int tamanho = dados.size();
    for (i = 0; i<tamanho; i++){        
        System.out.println(dados.get(i));
            if (x<dados.size() && dados.get(i).equals(dados.get(x++))){
            contador++;
            }
            System.out.print("repetiu:"); System.out.println(contador+1);
    } 
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new main().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Código de saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas essa é uma dúvida completamente diferente da outra, não acho interessante postar na mesma pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Use um [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) e o [o método `compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) para montar um histograma das palavras. Com o uso do [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), a ordenação já vem de graça:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class Frequencias {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> dados = new ArrayList<>();
        dados.add("Dado 2");
        dados.add("Dado 1");
        dados.add("Dado 3");
        dados.add("Dado 3");
        dados.add("Dado 2");
        dados.add("Dado 1");
        dados.add("Dado 3");
        dados.add("Dado 3");

        Map<String, Integer> frequencias = new TreeMap<>();
        for (String c : dados) {
            frequencias.compute(c, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
        }

        frequencias.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " aparece " + v + " vezes."));
    }
}
```

Essa é a saída produzida:

```
Dado 1 aparece 2 vezes.
Dado 2 aparece 2 vezes.
Dado 3 aparece 4 vezes.
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/pRgHXZ)

Answer (score 0):

Para contar a quantidade de ocorrências de um mesmo objeto/registro numa lista você pode usar o método estático `frequency()` da classe [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)).

Você precisa fazer apenas:

```
int qtdDado1 = Collections.frequency(dados, "Dado 1");
int qtdDado2 = Collections.frequency(dados, "Dado 2");
int qtdDado3 = Collections.frequency(dados, "Dado 3");
```

---

Fonte: [Mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-count-duplicated-items-in-java-list/)

Comment: Mas futuramente, os valores serão inseridos a partir de um txt, como eu faria uma forma genérica desse código?

Comment: @LucasSilva como assim?

Comment: Todos os dados inseridos no ArrayList são temporários, apenas para fazer a estrutura, assim que terminar, irei substituir para uma opção que ele receba os dados a partir de um txt, ai ele le e insere os dados no ArrayList